# Multiples of X from 1 to N

Tags: python, python-3.x, interpreter

The program accepts two integers (N, X) and prints all the multiples of X from 1 to N.

My code:

```py
    N, X = [int(val) for val in input().split()]
    for ctr in range(X,N+1):
         print(ctr, end=" ")
```

Expected output:

```
20 2

2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20
```

Actual output:

```
20 2

2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Comment: you are not checking if it is divisible or not. you are just printing it currently. to check you can put a simple if condition inside your for loop and use"%" to check if remainder is 0 or not

Answer (score 4):

```
N, X = [int(val) for val in input().split()]
for ctr in range(X, N+1, X):
     print(ctr, end=" ")
```

Add the step parameter to the `range` function.

Comment: Are you sure the step is N, not X?

Comment: it is not working it just showing the the value of X

Comment: Ordering was a bit confusing, but that's right. Thanks.

Comment: @Develper Sorry, I reflected MisterMiyagi's concern in the edit

Answer (score 3):

Because `range(X,N+1)` gives you all the numbers starting at X up to and including `N`, you never filter out for the numbers divisible by `x`.

Here's an approach where you generate all the multiples by finding the quotient of N / x:

```
>>> def foo(n, x):
...     quotient = n // x
...     return [i*x for i in range(1, quotient + 1)]
...
>>> foo(20, 2)
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
>>> foo(13, 3)
[3, 6, 9, 12]
```

Note, Python's `range` allows you to do this with a `step` parameter almost trivially:

```
>>> n,x = 20, 2
>>> list(range(x, n+ 1, x))
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
>>> n,x = 13, 3
>>> list(range(x, n+ 1, x))
[3, 6, 9, 12]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
N, X = [int(val) for val in input().split()]
for ctr in range(X,N+1):
     if ctr % X == 0:
         print(ctr, end=" ")
```

You can use the % (modulo) operator.

Basically, when you have a multiple of X, then the rest of the division of ctr by X is equal to 0.

That is what % checks for.

Comment: is there any other way by using range function

Comment: Well, I do not know why you would be looking for another way? I mean in maths, % is made for that particular problem.  So it is certainly the proper way to do?

Answer (score -2):

you are printing all numbers but what you want is all the multiples of x:

```
N, X = [int(val) for val in input().split()]
for ctr in range(1,N+1):
     print(X*ctr, end=" ")
```

Comment: This will print all multiples of `X` between `X` and `N*X`, not between `1` and `N`.

Comment: "have you tried it????" Sure. For `X=3` and `N=6` it will print "3 6 9 12 15 18 " instead of just "3 6 ".

Comment: i am extremely sorry to have mistaken the question. i am deleting my rude comments.....it will never happen again....